# Retrieve recipients from Outlook new mail

Tags: c#, visual-studio, outlook, vsto

We have an application whereby users can click a button that opens up a new email in Outlook. I am writing an add-in that will allow the user to add this email to an email scheduling application that we have written. (The delayed delivery functionality in Outlook is not very reliable).

Anyhow, the user needs to be able to modify the email, change the delivery date/time using a custom form I have created and then click a button to add it to our scheduler database.

My problem is when I try to access the recipients collection, if the recipient cannot be resolved, it is not recognized and doesn't appear in the recipients collection unless I save the mail item.

But if I save the mail item, it breaks the connection between the calling application which is expecting some confirmation that the email was sent. Currently I am sending the email back to the user after it is added to our scheduling system so that satisfies the calling application. But if I save the mail item first, it throws an error. I also don't have access to the source code of the calling application.

So what I need is a way to access the addresses entered in the To field without saving the mail item. Is this possible?

Comment: Why would you get an error when you save a messsage with an unresolved recipient? When are recipients accessed? If the cursor is still in the To edit box, the new recipient indeed will not be visible until you move the focus away from the To edit box or save the message.

Answer (score 0):

This article might help:

[Create and send an Outlook message programmatically](http://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/02/outlook-create-send-message/)

YOu can create a mail item and resolve the addresses without saving it.

Look for this line in the sample:

```
mailRecipient.Resolve();
```

What type of application is making the call to Outlook?

Comment: The problem is that the recipients collection is empty so I can't call mailRecipient.Resolve(). The user enters an smtp address in the To: field. When I attempt to call recipients.ResolveAll(), it simply clears the entered address from the text box. The mailItem.To field is empty as well. If I look at recipients.Count it is zero. The calling application was written in Delphi I believe.

Comment: Try calling YourMailItem.Save() before looping through your recipients.